# Clubbing query result based on single column data in JAVA

Tags: java, collections

Suppose below is the query Result:

```
Metrix No.  Org    Bus unit     Juris      Title
821         ABC  ABC Business    AZ       AZ cleanup
923         PQR  PQR Business    CT       CT Cleanup
923         PQR  PQR Business    N4       N4 Cleanup
923         PQR  PQR Business    N4       N4 add page
923         PQR  PQR Business    N3       N3 Cleanup
```

I want the result page as shown below:

```
Corp. Entity     Customer Segment    State        Project Description
   ABC           ABC Business        AZ           AZ Cleanup
   PQR           PQR Business        CT,N4,N3     CT Cleanup
```

Query result in stored in a bean. So we have a arraylist from where we get data in each row. I thought of using Map but it will store only 2 values at a time and I need 4 values corresponding to each record.

Can someone please suggest me some solution for this?

Thanks

Comment: An ArrayList isn't the ideal container for objects. Create a class that contains the data for the object, and store an instance of that class (i.e. Map `ID → Object`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your input, but using MAP was not feasible for me.

So I made one method which takes 'org' , the entire records and the index ( from where the iteration on records would start) as input parameter and gives STATE(as mentioned in result page) as output.

I also created one more Bean which had only those values which were required by the result page. I iterated the main list of records and whenever got new org , I passed the details to the method which provided me the combined State list. Then these values (Corp. Entity, Customer Segment, State , Project Description) was entered into new Bean.

Now while displaying the data, I iterated it through Array of new Bean which had only 4 values.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can solve problems like this with a `Map<KeyType,List<ValueType>>` and every time you find a value for a given key, add it to the value list. 
When you add the value for the first time, you need to take care of creating the list and adding the list to the map.

There are already existing implementations for this, if you don't mind using a library and don't want to do it yourself. For example the Multimap implementations of Guava (https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)

**Update:** If you can influence the SQL and the result data structure, another option would be to let the database take care of the aggregation. In MySQL, e.g., there is the `group_concat` function to aggregate values from a group into a single column.

Comment: But this type of map would give me pair of ABC->AZ and PQR ->CT,N4,N3.

Comment: What about the other two fields- Customer Segment and Project Description? They are taking values of the first record of Org i.e. first occurrence of ABC values and 1st Occurrence of PQR value in query result

Comment: Well, the rest of the collection and aggregation, you'd have to write yourself. The Multimap is just a tool here, not the entire solution for your problem.